# How to export and import strings resources files?

Tags: c#, winforms, resx

I created `strings.resx` and `strings.ar-EG.resx` to translate my project to English (default) and Arabic.

Now I would like to send this file to the translators to translate into French and Italian.

1. Is there any way to export the resource file (in easy layout) and then import it?
2. What about the forms labels (every form has two strings files beside it), can I export them in one file and then import them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resgen.exe Can be used to export the resx files to a text format that most localization services can use.